# Is {∅} ⊆ ∅? Set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is {∅} ⊆  ∅? I'm guessing no, as {∅} is a subset of {∅} but not of ∅. But I'm having doubts as ∅ is the only element in {∅} and ∅  is ∅.

Comment: You're right. This doesn't hold

Comment: The answer is indeed no. The correct explanation is that $\varnothing$ is an element of $\{\varnothing\}$ but not of $\varnothing$, so not every element $\{\varnothing\}$ is an element of $\varnothing$.

Comment: One is an empty box, the other is a box containing a smaller empty box. i.e. The empty set contains no elements but the set containing the empty set contains one.

Comment: $\{\phi\}$ means the set that has exactly one member, and that this sole member is $\phi$. A set with 1 member can't be a subset of the set with 0 members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition it follows that the only subset of the empty set is itself. By definition $\{ \phi \} \neq \phi$. So $\{ \phi \}$ is not a subset of $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed $\{ \emptyset \} \neq \emptyset$ since it has one element : $\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element i.e. $\varnothing$ while the set $\varnothing=\{ \}$ has no element. So the set inclusion doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed false.  For a nifty application of this investigate [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).  The naturals are defined as $\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\dots$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.